# RoR Devise: Always returns "Invalid Email or password" since a major update to the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I did a major code update, and post which all email/passwords have stopped working.
Not sure what to do, or what the issue is, want to get an idea of what could be possible reasons for this.

Its working fine for any new signups or any passwords that are reset.

Possible issues could be:
1. I changed the session store to activerecord from cookie session store

Answer (score 1):

Do you use git? 
If yes you can view the difference between the new code and the old one.
Then you should be able to track down the changes fix the bugs.

You need the command.

```
git diff
```

Comment: Yes, I use git but as I mentioned it was a major code change, and it seemed to work fine in development and staging, when I merged it into production, this error occurred, so it has **lots** of changes. Not easy to track down

Comment: When you run it in production you are using another db right? yourapp_development and yourapp_production? Then the data is simple not stored in yourapp_production?

Comment: yeah obviously different db, and users of production site are not able to log in with their previous passwords

Comment: yea well what you could do is also a dump in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890519/how-do-i-migrate-data-from-production-db-to-development-db-rails-4/24890699?noredirect=1#comment38666811_24890699) I have explained how this is possible. Then you will be able to use the same passwords for the production db.