# How do I migrate data from production db to development db (Rails 4)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I know this one sounds kind of backwards! I've been working on a cloud-based case-management application, and was working on a support-ticketing feature. We have our development database (MySQL) that has all the same data as our production database (It's a very large app). Development is basically a "sandbox" environment, hence why the development db has all the same as the production db. This morning, I ran into a problem in my local development server for:

```
Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.
```

Alright, did that, even though it didn't make any sense. It err'd out, because it was trying to create tables that already existed (I had already ran my migrations, the features were completed a day ago! And everything worked great).

The only thing that I did the moment before I got this message in my development server was uncomment an entirely-commented-out file to try and fix problems with TinyMCE (/config/tinymce.yml, text editor), followed by restarting my rails dev server. All this file was, was a bunch of defaults and plugins. When I saw the problem, I first commented them all back out. Still the same error. Proceeded with rake db: tasks.

Started looking for answers.. kept getting errors. Made a noob mistake, and ultimately did a

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

which I knew would rebuild the schema at the cost of hosing the db. This failed..  But we do have the db in more than one place (since it's the same as production.) Also, just to try and bring all the tables back:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

....failed on one of the tables anyway with

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `login` USING btree ON `users` (`login`, `intranet_id`)
```

..and all the tables are empty (as expected) that were successfully created. I'm by no means a database pro (I haven't dev'd very long). Am wondering, is there a way to copy the entire production database into the devel database? Tables, data, and all. Or any other suggestions? Really lost on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mysql_dump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/).

If you connect to the database everything is there -  you just have to do a dump of the full database and then do the dump again into the production tables.

As you clearly see you can output from the database with ">" and you can import with the "<".

Comment: It's a 6gb DB.. I'll give this a try. Thanks!